# MAAS node keeps re-installing Ubuntu 14.04 through PXE

Tags: maas, pxe

I'm trying to set up MAAS with about 8 nodes and I've been doing the automatic install through PXE which works great.  Problem is, every time I restart the machines through the MAAS web ui, the node re-installs the OS through PXE.  Should I be disabling PXE after the node is up and running so that it doesn't re-install every time?

Reason I ask is, I don't see this listed in the documentation anywhere, so I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to disable PXE on that machine.  Am I doing something wrong?

Edit #1 - BTW if I change the boot priority to set the PXE as the second boot, it drops me into the busybox mini shell and fails to start up.

Edit #2 Solution - Ended up having to set the rootdelay=90 on the kernel line of the boot loader and then setting the PXE boot to a lower priority fixes my issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling PXE boot altogether, just move the PXE boot a notch lower in the boot priority and then the systems will boot normally and will only start re-install when needed.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: That was my first thought, but I get another error stating something along the lines of "Gave up waiting for root device....." and drops me into a mini-shell.  I know the problem has to do with setting the root delay in the grub bootloader, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get to the point where I can modify the grub cfg.  (I'm still sitting on the screen which shows the "Gave up waiting for root device")

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide this crucial information, please?

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out.  Set the rootdelay=60 in the kernel startup and then changed it in the grub and updated it.  Going to suck if I have to do this on every machine everytime I have to re-install Ubuntu on a node.  Can't believe I wasted 4 hours on this problem.

Comment: Even better!  Post your own answer!  And the next guy/girl on the block will not have to waste 4 hours!  (on a Sunday!!!)  **;-)**